# XCODE4.6 UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode4.6

I'm having an issue in xcode 4.6.

MainStoryboard contains a Button & TableView. Apparently when I'm running the app and click the Button the Table view only shows the First Column and Last column of data.

I'm using sqlite3 where I have created a database and table that currently has one row of data consisting of 14 columns. First Column is the Primary Key for you info.

Below is my UITableViewCell Code * Action Button.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

DefenseStats *aDefenseStats = [arrayOfDefenseStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = aDefenseStats.defense_team_name_mp;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_games_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",aDefenseStats.defense_points_per_game_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",aDefenseStats.defense_yards_per_game_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",aDefenseStats.defense_rushing_yards_per_game_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",aDefenseStats.defense_passing_yards_per_game_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_interception_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_interception_touchdown_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_forced_fumble_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_defensive_touchdown_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_tackle_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_pass_deflection_mp];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_sack_mp];

return cell;
```

}

- (IBAction)displayDefenseStatsButton:(id)sender {

  sqlite3_stmt *statement;

  if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &americanfootballDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
      [arrayOfDefenseStats removeAllObjects];

  ```
  NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DEFENSE_TEAM_STATS"];
  const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

  if (sqlite3_prepare(americanfootballDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
      while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
      {

          NSString *defense_team_name_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
          NSString *defense_games_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
          NSString *defense_points_per_game_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
          NSString *defense_yards_per_game_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
          NSString *defense_rushing_yards_per_game_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
          NSString *defense_passing_yards_per_game_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
          NSString *defense_interception_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];
          NSString *defense_interception_touchdown_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];
          NSString *defense_forced_fumble_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];
          NSString *defense_defensive_touchdown_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];
          NSString *defense_tackle_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)];
          NSString *defense_pass_deflection_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 12)];
          NSString *defense_sack_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13)];

          DefenseStats *defensestats =[[DefenseStats alloc]init];

          [defensestats setDefense_team_name_mp:defense_team_name_string];
          [defensestats setDefense_games_mp:[defense_games_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_points_per_game_mp:[defense_points_per_game_string floatValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_yards_per_game_mp:[defense_yards_per_game_string floatValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_rushing_yards_per_game_mp:[defense_rushing_yards_per_game_string floatValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_passing_yards_per_game_mp:[defense_passing_yards_per_game_string floatValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_interception_mp:[defense_interception_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_interception_touchdown_mp:[defense_interception_touchdown_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_forced_fumble_mp:[defense_forced_fumble_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_defensive_touchdown_mp:[defense_defensive_touchdown_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_tackle_mp:[defense_tackle_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_pass_deflection_mp:[defense_pass_deflection_string intValue]];
          [defensestats setDefense_sack_mp:[defense_sack_string intValue]];

          [arrayOfDefenseStats addObject:defensestats];
      }
  }
  ```

  }
  [[self myTableView]reloadData];
  }
  */

Comment: Apologies for the way the comment has been posted.

Comment: There is a small "edit" link below your question that you can click to improve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're assigning to the same location (`cell.detailTextLabel.text`) over and over and over again, only the last one will count.  That's why you only see the last column.

`cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_sack_mp];`

I think what you really want is a cell for each column.  You'll get that with the following:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 14;
}
```

Then update your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to select the appropriate column value, probably with a 14-case `switch` statement and assign the value to `cell.textLabel.text`:

```
NSString *defenseStatValue;
switch (indexPath.row)
{
  case (0):
    defenseStatValue = aDefenseStats.defense_team_name_mp;
    break;
  case (1):
    defenseStatValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aDefenseStats.defense_games_mp];
    break;
  /* Add a case for each column index possible. */
}
cell.textLabel.text = defenseStatValue;
```

Also, don't assign anything to `cell.detailTextLabel.text`.

Comment: I'm trying to display my columns of data onto my tableview. Is there another way to display my data? In addition, it is also displaying data from my first column as well.